# Scatter plot with dates in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot

Could you help me make a scatter plot of the `df` database?. The x axis would be the dates and the y axis would be the values corresponding to d1 and d2. Also, I would like to put as x-axis caption "date" and y-axis caption "d".

```
  df <- structure(
      list(date = c("2021-01-01","2021-01-02","2021-01-03","2021-01-04","2021-01-05"),
           d1 = c(0,1,4,5,6), d2 = c(2,4,5,6,7)),class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Have you done any searching.(You are expected to have done extensive searching.) There must be hundreds of solved questions involving graphing with R dates. R dates are actually a specific class and you need to do some work to understand their structure. This seems quite simple, so you could probably get better responses if you linked to questions that you have reviewed and had difficulty understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the data in long format for the `d1` and `d2` variables.

Using `ggplot2` here is one way to plot this data -

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -date) %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(date, value, color = name) + 
  geom_point(size = 2) + 
  labs(x = 'date', y = 'd') + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for replying Ronak Shan. But if I want to change it by chance: leave the values corresponding to d1 and d2 on the axis x and the y axis as the dates, then how would it look?

Comment: You can add `+ coord_flip()` to the above code.

Comment: One last question: if I have a d3 and d4 for example. How would I merge with d1 and d2 ? Thank you so much!